# Geometric probability; circle and two points

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

On a circumference of circle which radius is 1, two points are chosen randomly. What is the probability that the distance between these two points is less then 1?

The solution from my book is $\frac{1}{3}$. I don't have an idea to solve this.

Comment: Fix the first point.  Which points on the circle are within distance $1$ of it?

Comment: @saulspatz So two points from left and right side of fixed point, let's call them A and B, are exactly on distance 1 away from the fixed point. So if I choose any point from the curve AB distance will definitely be less then 1?

Comment: Yes, they will be.  Draw a picture.  If the fixed point is P, and X is a point on PA, imagine rotating the segment PX until it falls on PA.

Comment: Okay I understand the concept, might sound silly but still don't understand how is the probability $\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say the circle is centered at $O$ and fix one point at $P$.  Let $A$ and $B$ be the two points on the circle at distance $1$ from $P$.  $\angle AOP=60^\circ$ (draw a picture to see the equilateral triangle,) so $\angle AOB=120^\circ$, one-third of the circle.